# How do I bind wx.CLOSE_BOX to a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer.  I have a GUI which has a cancel button that asks the user to abort all unsaved changes when they press it.  The GUI also has a `wx.CLOSE_BOX`, but this simply closes it because its not bound to my `OnCancel` function. How do I bind it?

Things I tried:

````
 self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, lambda event: self.OnCancel(event, newCRNum), wx.CLOSE_BOX)  
 #This gives an AssertionError, replacing wx.EVT_CLOSE with wx.EVT_BUTTON also
 #  gives the same error

 self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, lambda event: self.OnCancel(event, newCRNum))  
 #This binds any time ```self.Close(True)``` occurs (which makes sense) but
 #  is not what I want.  There are other buttons which close the GUI which should not
 #  use the OnCancel function
````

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT:** The code below should help clarify what I'm looking for

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        newCRNum = 0
        cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Cancel")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.OnCancel(event, newCRNum), cancelBtn)

    def OnCancel(self, event, CRNum):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "Are you sure you want to cancel? All work will be lost and CR number will not be reserved.", "Cancel CR", wx.YES_NO|wx.NO_DEFAULT|wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)       
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_YES:
            self.Destroy()
        else:
            dlg.Destroy

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

So what this does is create a whimsically large cancel button. When this button is pressed, a dialog box pops up and prompts the user if they really want to quit.  If they say yes, the whole gui closes, if not, only the dialog box closes.

When the user presses the red (X) button in the top right of the GUI, I want the same thing to happen.  Since is a button, I assume it can be bound to my `OnCancel` button, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Reason for `AssertionError`:  The third argument must be `source` widget like follow.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, lambda event: self.OnCancel(event, newCRNum), self)
```

Try following example:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        newCRNum = 0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, lambda event: self.OnCancel(event, newCRNum))
    def OnCancel(self, event,  num):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Do you want close?', 'Sure?',
                               wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            event.Skip()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately its not quite what I'm looking for.  Your answer is the same as my second attempt, it binds any close action to the ```OnCancel``` function, which is not what I want.  I've revised the question so that this is more clear.

Comment: @wnnmaw, How about remove `Bind` and call `OnCancel` explicitly before the `self.Close(..)`?

Comment: So I would create a generic close function that then passes to the correct function?  That's very clever, but would require a very big overhaul of my code :(

Comment: @wnnmaw, Or you can override `Close`.

Comment: What do you mean? How would I do that?

Comment: @wnnmaw, Something like `def Close(self, *args, **kwargs): self.OnClose(...); super(ClassName, self).Close(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41476/discussion-between-wnnmaw-and-falsetru)